# Get git commit info by dates with stash rest api

Tags: git, date, git-commit, bitbucket-server

Is there a way to get git commits info by dates with stash rest API?

I have searched developer documentation, and learned that you could get commits info with commit id and so on, but not with date.

https://developer.atlassian.com/stash/docs/latest/reference/rest-api.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the reference document for the [Atlassian Stash REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/2.7.1/stash-rest.html#idp2466752).

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/commits
```

can be used to retrieve a page of changesets from a given starting commit or between two commits. The commits may be identified by branch or tag name or by hash. A path may be supplied to restrict the returned changesets to only those which affect that path

Sample response

```
{
    "size": 1,
    "limit": 25,
    "isLastPage": true,
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "def0123abcdef4567abcdef8987abcdef6543abc",
            "displayId": "def0123",
            "author": {
                "name": "charlie",
                "emailAddress": "charlie@example.com"
            },
            "authorTimestamp": 1377738985925,
            "message": "More work on feature 1",
            "parents": [
                {
                    "id": "abcdef0123abcdef4567abcdef8987abcdef6543",
                    "displayId": "abcdef0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "start": 0,
    "filter": null,
    "authorCount": 1,
    "totalCount": 1
}
```

You could use **authorTimestamp** to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to parse authorTimestamp to meet my specific need.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for commits in Bitbucket Server and DC can still be challenging. However, you can do the following:

- You can take advantage of Sourcetree when you work with a limited number of repositories.
- Use the Awesome Graphs for Bitbucket app when
  you need a more comprehensive approach to search and analytics in
  Bitbucket.
- Get the list of commits in the repository with the help of
  Bitbucket REST API.
  You can find more information in this blog post: https://stiltsoft.com/blog/2021/05/how-to-search-for-commits-in-bitbucket-server-and-data-center/